# Why do Eclipse APIs use Arrays instead of Collections?

Tags: eclipse, api, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the Eclipse APIs, the return and argument types are mostly arrays instead of collections. An example is the `members` method on `IContainer`, which returns `IResources[]`.

I am interested in why this is the case. Maybe it is one of the following:

1. The APIs were designed before generics generics were available, so `IResource[]` was better than just `Collection` or `List`
2. Memory concerns, e.g. `ArrayList` internally holds an array which has more space than is needed (to offer an efficient implementation of `add`), whereas an array is always constructed for just the needed target size
3. It's not possible to add/remove elements on an array, so it is safe for iterating (but defensive copying is still necessary, because one can still change elements, e.g. set them to `null`)

Does anyone have any insights or other ideas why the API was developed that way?

Comment: Just a guess but it was probably created before Java introduced generics so the only typed collections at the time were arrays.

Comment: Eclipse predates generics and they are really serious about API stability.  Also, at the low level of SWT passing arrays seems to be used to reflect the operating system APIs that are being wrapped.  Once you have a bunch of tooling using Arrays I guess it makes sense to keep things consistent.  Also note that arrays aren't subject to all of the type erasure issues when using reflection.

Comment: @Robert you should post your comment as the answer. It's right on.

Comment: @Robert Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. BTW, my main gripe with continuing to use arrays in new APIs is that it makes the use of `System.arrayCopy` and `collection.toArray(new IResource[collection.size()])` necessary everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, so it can be accepted.

Eclipse predates generics and they are really serious about API stability. Also, at the low level of SWT passing arrays seems to be used to reflect the operating system APIs that are being wrapped. Once you have a bunch of tooling using Arrays I guess it makes sense to keep things consistent. Also note that arrays aren't subject to all of the type erasure issues when using reflection.

Yeah, I hear you as far as the collections api being generally much easier to work with for dynamic lists of items.